# How to call method of third or higher parent class using method of child class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a RESTful API by means of Django RestFramework. I need to call the validation method (say method a) of a class (say RawUser) in subclasses. For the first two levels "super()" can help, but I do not know the solution for the deeper levels. This is my sample code:

```
class RawUser:
    def a(self):
        return 'something'


class AnonymousUser(RawUser):
    def a(self):
        return super().a()


class RegisteredUser(AnonymousUser):
    def a(self):
        return super(AnonymousUser, self).a()


class VIPUser(RegisteredUser):
    def a(self):
        # How can I call method "a" of RawUser here?


class SpecialUser(VIPUser):
    def a(self):
        # How can I call method "a" of RawUser here?


class AdminUser(SpecialUser):
    def a(self):
        # How can I call method "a" of RawUser here?
```

I need to call the method "a" of RawUser in deep subclasses for example AdminUser. How can I do this?

Comment: If you need to access `RawUser` directly that deep in the hierarchy, your hierarchy probably isn't right. For example, if `VIPUser` needs to call `Rawuser.a` instead of `RegisteredUser.a`, then `RegisteredUser` probably isn't the right base class. (Or `a` isn't provided by the correct class.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need the other methods that only available in the higher class. So I need this hierarchy inheritance.

Comment: No, you need *an* inheritance hierarchy, but this may not be the *correct* one. `a` could, for instance, be better modeled as two separate methods provided by different classes, allowing more specialized (multiple) inheritance to be used to make sure each class gets the `a` it needs.

Comment: Yeah, now I got your idea. This is far far better. Thank u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RawUser.a(instance)
```

When you call instance.method() you are actually calling Class.method(instance), the self is actually an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I can import RawUser class and use it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing you already do in `RegisteredUser`.

Just use `super(AnonymousUser, self).a()` in every class except AnonymousUser and RawUser. This will only call RawUser and the class you're in. I've [tested it here](https://replit.com/@12944qwerty/testing#main.py)